# How to correctly advertise my mobile app on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-play, facebook-ads

I created a Facebook page for my app and then I started creating an add, and for the button label I choose 'download' and when I paste my app's play store link as the 'website URL' it says that the link is invalid. What am I doing wrong?
[image]